# undesired behaviour: makefile executes shell script while parsing

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a script which generates some source files for my c++ project.
The script itself looks like this:

```
echo "total args: $#"
if [ $# -eq 7 ]; then
echo "in if"
$1/../tools/xsde [...]
fi
```

It is executed from a makefile when target smt_response_files is run and file .xsd.files.make does not exists or it is older than .xsd file.

```
$(smt_path) ?= .
$(smt_build) ?= $(smt_path)/build
$(common_build) ?= ../build

-include $(smt_build)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd).files.make

smt_response_files : | $(smt_build)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd).files.make
    @:

$(smt_build)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd).files.make : $(smt_gen_response_path)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd)
    @$(common_build)/generate_xml.sh $(smt_path) $(smt_gen_response_path) $(smt_gen_response_xsd) xml::$(smt_gen_response_class) make_list $(smt_build)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd).files.make smt_response_files
```

The problem: after I clean up my project and delete *.xsd.files.make they are recreated when makefiles are parsed (I've translated the output from Russian):

```
Reading make-files...
total args: 7
in if
...
total: 2193
Updating makefile goals...
 File `smt_clean' does not exist.
... (and a normal clean proccess goes next)
```

The autogenerated files are removed by the clean target, but I don't like that they are created in the process.

The only way to do this, as far as I know is to exclude the rules for recreating *.xsd.files.make which are included as makefiles:

```
inc_gen ?= true
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    inc_gen := false
endif
# ... other excluded targets here (smt_clean, etc.)

ifeq ($(inc_gen),true)
$(smt_build)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd).files.make : $(smt_gen_response_path)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd)
    @$(common_build)/generate_xml.sh $(smt_path) $(smt_gen_response_path) $(smt_gen_response_xsd) xml::$(smt_gen_response_class) make_list $(smt_build)/$(smt_gen_response_xsd).files.make smt_response_files
endif
```

Is there other ways to solve my problem? Maybe some more general approach exists?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're technically not built as the makefile is parsed.  See the GNU make manual, section *How Makefiles are Remade*.  Once make finishes parsing all the makefiles, it will perform a pass where it makes sure that all the included makefiles are up to date, by treating them all as if they were targets and trying to rebuild them.  That's what you're seeing.

If any makefile has changed, then make will re-execute itself from scratch so it can re-read the contents of the updated makefiles.

The solution you have (where you check for the `clean` target, and any other targets you don't want to force a rebuild of makefiles, and if it's found you either don't do the `include` or you don't provide the rules to rebuild the makefiles) is the recommended solution.

Remember that rules like `clean`, `all`, etc. are just conventions: they mean nothing to make any more than rules like `foo` or `bar`.  So, make cannot know to treat them specially.